# How can I add a .aar file as a package in my flutter android application?

Tags: java, android, flutter, sdk

I just received a `*.aar` file from my vendor, which turned out to be the SDK I need to use to consume their service. But since my application is in Flutter how can I import that SDK and use its methods from my flutter application.

Answer (score 2):

Add .aar files under `android/libs/` folder.

Then edit `build.gradle` like this.

```
buildscript { 
     repositories { 
         google() 
         jcenter() 
         flatDir { 
             dirs 'libs' 
         } 
     } 
  
     dependencies { 
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1' 
     } 
 } 
  
 rootProject.allprojects { 
     repositories { 
         google() 
         jcenter() 
         flatDir { 
             dirs 'libs' 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

```
dependencies { 
     //rx Android for updating status 
     implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1' 
     implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19' 
  
 //    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs') 
  
     implementation files('libs/xUtils-2.5.5.jar') //implementation files('org.xutils:xutils:2.5.+') 
     implementation files('libs/jxl.jar') 
     implementation(name: 'DeviceAPI-20211216', ext: 'aar') 
  
     //implementation files('/Users/apple/Desktop/sdks/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-x64/flutter.jar') 
  
 }
```

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  [Edit] your answer and copy-paste it into the answer itself in between \`\`\` the code \`\`\`.

Comment: And how do I import and use its methods?

Comment: https://github.com/yushulx/flutter-android-aar as normal import. check this repo.

Comment: if you're happy with the answer you should mark it correct and up vote it,,thanks